# Missing values on dmarc test : ruf & rua

Tags: dmarc

I was testing my DMARC on gmass.co and i got some messing values.
it's about the ruf & rua. I would like to know if this is someting important to add ?

```
DMARC Record Found:

 v=DMARC1;p=none;sp=none;adkim=r;aspf=r;pct=100;fo=0;rf=afrf;ri=86400
Tag Name    Purpose Value
v   Protocol version    DMARC1
pct Percentage of messages subjected to filtering   100
ruf Reporting URI for forensic reports  MISSING
rua Reporting URI of aggregate reports  MISSING
p   Policy for organizational domain    none
sp  Policy for subdomains of the OD none
adkim   Alignment mode for DKIM r
aspf    Alignment mode for SPF  r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good article on both `rua` and `ruf`: https://dmarcian.com/rua-vs-ruf/. Basically, you don't need `ruf` and
`rua` is very handy if you want to move from `p=none` to `p=reject`.

`rua` lets you analyse how your emails are being received by receiving servers and what you might need to do to make all mail flows DMARC compliant.